# How to know the dragging element is over which element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a problem with jQuery Drag&Drop. I have a draggable element and lots of dropTarget so I just want to know when I am dragging, my dragging element is over which element?

Btw, Firefox provides event.originalTarget that points an DOM Element but it is equal to "undefined" in Google Chrome.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [`over`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-over) event on your droppables.

```
$('#droppableid').droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
        log('You are over item with id ' + this.id);
    }
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/mqxpW/).

Comment: I should know the element's details on drag not drop. When user dragging, I want to append a created element before or after the dropable. Btw, I always use the dropable word in this case, but 'the dropable' elements are not jQuery dropable. They are just span element.

Comment: This tells you when something is _over_ the droppable - i.e. when it is being dragged - not when it is dropped. There is no info on the draggable to tell you what it's over, and nothing on plain span elements - so I would suggest making your span elements 'droppable' and using the `over` method above. To append before or after the element, you can use the `before` and/or `after` jquery methods. http://api.jquery.com/before/